# how compare two text file in python and delete duplicate?

Tags: python, python-re

I am new in python. I have two text file contains list of url. I want to compare text1 file with text2 file and remove text2 matching url from text1 file.

my text file look like this:

**text2**

```
https://www.basketbal.vlaanderen/clubs/detail/bbc-wervik
https://www.basketbal.vlaanderen/clubs/detail/bbc-alsemberg
https://www.basketbal.vlaanderen/clubs/detail/koninklijk-basket-team-ion-waregem
https://www.basketbal.vlaanderen/clubs/detail/basket-poperinge
```

**text1**

```
https://www.basketbal.vlaanderen/clubs/detail/bbc-erembodegem
https://www.basketbal.vlaanderen/clubs/detail/dbc-osiris-okapi-aalst
https://www.basketbal.vlaanderen/clubs/detail/the-tower-aalst
https://www.basketbal.vlaanderen/clubs/detail/gsg-aarschot
https://www.basketbal.vlaanderen/clubs/detail/bbc-wervik #duplicate url from text2
https://www.basketbal.vlaanderen/clubs/detail/bbc-alsemberg #duplicate url from text 2
```

After google searching I found few solutions but those solutions only remove duplicate from current file.

**pandas solution** for removing duplicate

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset ="link", keep ='first', inplace = True)
```

**python regex**

```
import re
re.sub('<.*?>', '', string) #it's not removing duplicate just replacing string with with nothing ('').
```

I didn't find any better solution how to compare two text file in python for removing duplicate. If any text1 file url match with text2 file then matching url delete from text1 file. Any idea how to do it in python?

Comment: Convert each file into a `set` of lines. Then use `set1 - set2` to remove any items that are duplicated between the two files.

Comment: give samples of both files.......... name the files clearly (text1 and text2)............. and let us know which of the two files do you want modified?

Comment: Why do you need a regular expression? There's no `<>` in the file contents, why do yuo have them in the regexp?

Comment: Barmar  thanks for your commnet. I updated my question  as you wanted to know how look like my text1 and text2 file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of the files doesn't matter, you can do this:

```
with open("file1.txt") as f1:
    set1 = set(f1.readlines())
with open("file2.txt") as f2:
    set2 = set(f2.readlines())

nondups = set1 - set2

with open("file1.txt", "w") as out:
    out.writelines(nondups)
```

This converts the contents of each file to a set of lines. Then it removes the common elements from the first set, and writes that result back to the first file.

Comment: Make sure there's no extra whitespace in the lines.

Comment: Barmar it worked. just wante to know what is doing `set` ?

Comment: Read about the `set` datatype: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use pandas to solve this you can go like this.

```
    import pandas as pd 
    
    df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.txt',names=['link'])
    df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.txt',names=['link'])
    df1[~df1.link.isin(df2.link)].to_csv('file1_clean.csv',index=False)
```

this block of code will return a file containing the file1.txt data in csv format but without the links from file2.txt